# Disable the public-read permission to AllUsers (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

I was setting the permission to AllUsers for uploading the files, 
I used:

```
gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://[mywebsite.com]
gsutil defacl set public-read gs://[mywebsite.com]
```

but I found the directory was wrong.
So I wanna disable the permission to the current directory.
First, I checked the IAM policy for my setting by
`gsutil iam get gs://[mywebsite.com]`
and the part of the results show:

```
{
      "members": [
        "allUsers", 
        "projectViewer:[myprojectID]"
      ], 
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketReader"
    }
```

I guess it means the permission to all users, so I have to disable it.

Then, removing AllUsers from this directory by:

```
gsutil iam ch -d All gs://[mywebsite.com]
```

However....it can't work......it shows

```
CommandException: Incorrect public member type for binding AllUsers:R
```

Is there any solution to this ?

If I delete the bucket, the permission will also disabled?

(Update) Does "public-read" mean user can read the directory that you set? or just the permission to upload files to the Storage? (this is what I really wanna know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the syntax mentioned in `gsutil help iam ch`, it says to specify `allUsers`, not `AllUsers`. This works when you specify the former, but throws an error for the latter.

Case sensitivity for removing users/roles was fixed for `acl ch -d` in [this GitHub commit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/commit/5039cc9795df59a5bda79c5ff23de0c4c96d0239), but it looks like it was never fixed for `iam ch -d`. I've opened a [GitHub issue for this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/473).